# Is there any best practice about how to organize methods?

Tags: java, methods

This might be somewhat of a theoretical question, let me try to explain it with an example:

- I have a POJO `Cow` and a POJO `Calving`
- Every `Cow` has a list of `Calving`s

There is a check in the code that every Calving needs at least a 7 month window, this means that, if a new Calving is added

- There has to be a validation that the Calving before the newly added one, is at least 7 months *before* the newly added one **and**;
- in case there is a Calving after the newly added one, it has to be at least 7 months *after* the newly added one.

Now, I wonder what the best practice is for where to put the method to validate the newly added calving. I have 2 possible solutions:

**Option 1:**

I make following methods in my Cow class:

- `private Calving getPreviousCalving(Date calvingDate)`
- `private Calving getNextCalving(Date calvingDate)`
- `public boolean isCalvingIn7MonthWindow(Date dateToCheck)`

**Option 2:**

I make following methods in my Cow class:

- `public Calving getPreviousCalving(Date calvingDate)`
- `public Calving getNextCalving(Date calvingDate)`

And this one in my Calving class:

- `public boolean isIn7MonthWindow(Calving calvingBefore, Calving calvingAfter, Date dateToCheck)`

The reason I'm in doubt is that the `isIn7MonthWindow` method gives information about a potential new Calving (option 2), not about a Cow, so logical it should be in the Calving class no? However, option 1 is much cleaner and has easier access to all necessary data to do the check (as Cow has a Calving list).

I hope this isn't too broad and is not opinion based. Any thoughts?

Comment: This question appears to be only about opinions... Your question appears to be more about constructors than methods. Since you want to only add `Object`s under a condition, IMHO I believe that a `private boolean Cow.birth()` method would be best, in it, you check if its `Calving` list allows for a new one, then instantiate it, and add to that List, otherwise, return false. Also, since `Cow/Calving` appears to be independant classes, this could save you the "pain" of dealing with changing the program later on, and having to re-check most rules.

Comment: I am not sure why the class Calving actually exists. Why not just have the class Cow, and a method giveBirth( new Cow(...) ) that would throw an exception if the timing were incorrect. This is along the same lines as the suggestion by @Bonatti

Comment: Does calving happen to be a subclass of cow? If so, no one calving should know about the existence of another calving (i.e. your methods checking for others existence should NOT exist in the `Calving` class ).

Comment: @FredK Because not every 'new' cow due to calving has to be registered right away, but I agree that it would be a good solution if it had to be.
@DovahkiinvasNormandy No, no inheritance between the two. `Cow` has a list of `Calving`. That's the only 'link' there is between the two.

Comment: @Bonatti I was afraid that it was opinion based indeed... so I guess there is no 'best practice' or rules to follow looking at the close votes I see. Your suggestion does seem nice thou, guess that is the way I'll go if it is about validation of objects in a list.